# onListItemClick generates ForceClose when clicking on item of list

Tags: android, listview

I am using following code:

```
public class myclass extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{  
//oncreate()  
   {.............}      
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

//.....

startActivityForResult(intentname,0);
myclass.this.finish();  
}  
}
```

Problem is>>  When i click any item in list by mouse(for test on vm) it shows Force Close  But works fine with Return(Enter) key...

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Force close is generated by an exception that should appear in log cat. Post this exception here to get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this..

place the below given code in `OnListItemClickListener`..

> Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
>           String place = o.toString();

Comment: I have found this code from Sai Geetha's Blog and used just before you suggested ..then also Thanks for Replying.  And thanks to all others..

Answer (score 0):

You have to `@Override` the `onListItemClick()`.  
Are you doing that?

Comment: @kgiannakakis Yes I have tried Override but it didn't worked  @Bill Mote My Logcat generated is as follows:
> Shutting down VM  >threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)  >Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception  >java.lang.NullPointerException >at com.demo.listdir.onListItemClick(listdir.java:84)  >at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:312)  >android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3246) >at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick...

Comment: also when I use l.getSelectedItemPosition() to view in logcat on click gives -1 while return key gives original position so there is a problem... Is there any event that gives item position on click by mouse click.??